# Snubber Circuit working

Tags: ac, control, triac, phase

[image]How does snubber circuit work in phase control circuit of Single Phase AC Motor? I have tried to know the causes but I was confused with RC circuit function with this phase control circuit.

Comment: Do you have an example circuit diagram because without one, your question is a bit vague?

Comment: dV/dt limiting. For EMI reasons or otherwise. It might also help to trigger the TRIAC at light load, but that would probably not be the intended or primary purpose.

Comment: Where does your AC supply interface?

Comment: Sorry. Forget to draw.

Comment: It looks like there is some mistake in the schematic.  Does this look correct: https://oskog97.com/sshin/314745.png ?

Comment: Sorry. I have drawn again with a correct schematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply, the snubber provides a load to dissipate energy from rapid changes in voltage associated with reactive components.  In your diagram, consider what happens when the triac experiences a voltage spike.  The triac itself has capacitance  between the line and the gate, and the spike may provide enough current through this capacitance to turn it "on."

The capacitor provides a high current path through the resistor to ground, preventing the spike voltage from rising quickly and providing a resistive load to dissipate the energy.  At lower frequencies (like the motor frequency) the capacitor impedance is high and the current is low.

Comment: I thought the inductor was the motor, until I saw the circle on the left.

Comment: It's actually a pretty good question - can someone edit the schematic?

Comment: OP has corrected the schematic now.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

A triac is a form of thyristor, so it can't turn off when current is flowing.  And if the triac never switches off while current is flowing through the inductor, the snubber is completely useless.

But of course, the world we live in is not ideal and the triac will turn off before the current has completely stopped, so my guess is that the snubber forms a path for the current that is too low to go correctly through the triac.

If you're using a device that can turn off (eg. MOSFETs or gate-turn-off thyristors), then the snubber deals with the full load.